# See if new data equals old data, if old data equals new data do nothing. Else rename old data to new data

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

As my bad title describes I want to check if my new data equals my old data.
If the new data equals old data: do nothing.
If the new data is not equal to old data: change old data to new data. 
Then repeat the whole process with the new definition for old data.

Made this code, but as you can see, every time old data is redefined at the end
Its redefined again when running the code once more.

```
def ask_data_change():
    data_inn = 'old data'    
    my_data_input = input('What is your input?: ')


    if data_inn == my_data_input:
        #does nothing
        print('Data input is equal to existing data')
        print('data unchanged: ' + data_inn)
    else:
        #Changes data_inn to new data input
        data_inn = my_data_input
        print('Data is not equal to existing, changing data_inn to my_data_input')
        print('New data is now: ' + data_inn)


while True:
    ask_data_change()
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you're redefining `data_inn` on each call, move your `while` loop into the function itself and have the old data redefined outside:

```
def ask_data_change():
    data_inn = 'old data'
    while True:    
        my_data_input = input('What is your input?: ')

        if data_inn == my_data_input:
            #does nothing
            print('Data input is equal to existing data')
            print('data unchanged: ' + data_inn)
        else:
            #Changes data_inn to new data input
            data_inn = my_data_input
            print('Data is not equal to existing, changing data_inn to my_data_input')
            print('New data is now: ' + data_inn)

ask_data_change()
```

The other option is to make `data_inn` as a global variable so, again, it doesn't get redefined in the function:

```
data_inn = 'old data'

def ask_data_change():
    global data_inn   
    my_data_input = input('What is your input?: ')
    if data_inn == my_data_input:
        #does nothing
        print('Data input is equal to existing data')
        print('data unchanged: ' + data_inn)
    else:
        #Changes data_inn to new data input
        data_inn = my_data_input
        print('Data is not equal to existing, changing data_inn to my_data_input')
        print('New data is now: ' + data_inn)

while True:
    ask_data_change()
```

Comment: I feel like suggesting `global` use is a bad idea.

Comment: @FHTMitchell - Your answer doesn't differ in function from the `global` version above. Whether you give a function the ability to alter its outside scope or you alter it by explicitly assigning the return value from it is just a code-style choice. I would discourage usage of `global`, too, as I personally prefer explicit outside-scope assignments but that comes down to personal tastes.

Comment: Of course, but you've seen the sort of mess we get with on SO with overuse of `global`. I've used `global` maybe twice in my entire development history. Beginners tend to use it if they know about it because they find it conceptually easy, but it causes a lot of problems they don't anticipate so I tend not to even tell them it exists unless surrounded by a lot of warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Because every time you run the function, all the values are reset. This is known as scoping (values defined in a function call stay in that function call **unless returned**.

See here:

```
def f():
    i = 0
    i += 1
    print(i)

for _ in range(3):
    f()
```

Output:

```
1
1
1
```

As you can see, `i` is being redefined in the function each time, it does not hold it's value from before. You'll need to return your new value and then pass it to the function on each iteration like so:

```
def ask_data_change(data_inn):
    my_data_input = input('What is your input?: ')  

    if data_inn == my_data_input:
        #does nothing
        print('Data input is equal to existing data')
        print('data unchanged: ' + data_inn)
    else:
        #Changes data_inn to new data input
        data_inn = my_data_input
        print('Data is not equal to existing, changing data_inn to my_data_input')
        print('New data is now: ' + data_inn)

    return data_inn


data_inn = 'old data'
while True:
     data_inn = ask_data_change(data_inn)
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time that `ask_data_change()` is called in the outer function, you're resetting both your values

Assuming you want to stop the loop when you type different input, try this

```
def ask_data_change():
    data_inn = 'old data' 
    my_data_input = input('What is your input?: ')

    while data_inn == my_data_input:
        #does nothing
        print('Data input is equal to existing data')
        print('data unchanged: ' + data_inn)
        my_data_input = input('What is your input?: ')

    #Changes data_inn to new data input
    data_inn = my_data_input
    print('Data is not equal to existing, changing data_inn to my_data_input')
    print('New data is now: ' + data_inn)
    return data_inn # Assuming you want this value 

data_inn = ask_data_change()
```